# Generated SAS Authorization failure

Tags: .net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am new to azure and just created an account on azure portal to test out blob storage.

I am trying out the example for authorizing with SAS here with the SDK for .net.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-dotnet-get-started

```
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient
        (new Uri($"{blobUri}?{sasToken}"), null);

        var containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("testcontainer");

        if (containerClient.Exists())  //error
            Console.WriteLine("yes");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("no");

        var blobs = containerClient.GetBlobs().ToList(); //error

        foreach (var x in blobs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x.Name);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

I am receiving the error:-

```
Azure.RequestFailedException: 'This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
```

This is how my settings look like when generating the SAS token

[image: SAS Generationg]

I don't think the access level setting to Private matters here with my generated SAS token.

Answer (score 0):

- A work around would be to use the SAS URL provided in the portal as we then create the url anyway using the sas token.

[image]

- Here I am downloading data of a blob from azure blob storage to a file in local machine.

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized;

namespace ConsoleApp7
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
           // Connection to BLob 
            BlobServiceClient blob_serviceClient = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri("<URL FROM PORTAL>"), null);
            
            //Refrence of the Container
            BlobContainerClient c = blob_serviceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("test");
            
            //Refrence of Blob
            BlobClient v = c.GetBlobClient("a.json");
        
           // Downloading the blob
            await v.DownloadToAsync("<lOCAL FILE PATH>");
            


        }
    }
}
```

Before running the program:

[image]

after execution:

[image]

Comment: I have done the exact same thing. You haven't added anything of significance.

Comment: I was able to interact with blob storage with the same permissions as you So try regenerating tokens/URL and add more permissions